# Componentes FREE (Upload, Email e Jpeg) em ASP 3

Tags: asp

Preciso substituir os componentes pagos:

http://www.aspemail.com/ 
http://www.aspjpeg.com/ 
http://www.aspupload.com/

Alguém conhece alternativas boas e FREE. Tô afim de economizar uma grana, já que juntando os três dará 600 doletas.

Comment: Acho que esse tipo de discussão cabe melhor no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha).

Comment: Tem ninguém lá. em todo caso agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você estiver falando de ***ASP Classic***

Manipulação de Imagem:

[Image Resize](http://easierthan.blogspot.com/2013/02/code-tip-3-classic-asp-image-resizer.html)

[csImageFile](https://www.chestysoft.com/imagefile/default.asp) (É 140 doláres, **já melhora**)

Enviar e-mail:

[Crystone](http://www.crystone.com/support/faq/sending-emails-with-classic-asp)

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_send_email.asp)

[Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/754136/Send-Email-using-Classic-ASP)

Upload de Arquivos:

[Pergunta no Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190305/how-to-upload-files-with-asp-classic)

[Microsoft Docs](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/299692/how-to-upload-files-to-a-web-server-by-using-asp)

Answer (score 1):

Para o envio de e-mail, não precisa de componente, no ISS você tem o CDO.SYS, ele faz parte do IIS a partir da versão 6. Aqui tem um exemplo de como mandar uma mensagem com ele:

https://ajuda.locaweb.com.br/wiki/cdosys/

Para o upload de arquivos, você pode dar uma olhada no pure-upload

https://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/pure-asp-upload.htm

Para redimensionar imagens, se o servidor tiver o Office Web Components instalado, você pode dar uma olhada neste script:

https://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_asp-resize-image/

Comment: Boa cara. Sobre o CDDOSYS precisa ativar algo no IIS? Se eu fizer o script já funciona? O pure-upload é bem confuso, vou precisar de algum tempo pra entender, mas acho que será a solução.

Comment: Até onde eu me lembro, precisa ter o SMTP instalado (porta 25)